# Tools for assembling textures into DDS files

Tags: textures, tools

There are plenty of tools for making images. I'm not looking for one of those; I have many tools for creating an image. I've got tools for compressing images, generating mipmaps, and even for poking at their basic data format.

My issue is with texture assembly. DDS files support cubemaps, array textures, and even cubemap arrays. But I don't know of a tool that can pack a series of images into a cubemap or the like. What tools are available for doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called DxTex. It comes with the DirecX SDK (Utilities folder). It can create Mipmaps, Cubemaps, Volumemaps and several other things you might want to do with your textures.

Comment: According to the documentation for the tool, it only handles DDS9-format DDS's. So no array textures or cubemap arrays. But it does handle cubemaps.

Comment: I just checked and there is indeed no support for texture arrays or cubemap arrays.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the nvassemble tool shipped with nVidia's Texture Tools 2 suite should be able to assemble image files into volume textures, cube maps and texture arrays.

http://code.google.com/p/nvidia-texture-tools/wiki/CommandLineTools

Unfortunately, the parts necessary for volume texture and texure array assembly are commented out in the accompanying source code and I could not find a reason for that.

EDIT:
Some time ago I contacted the author of the nVidia Texture Tools (Ignacio Castano) to find out why some parts of the nvassemble code are commented out. Here's what he had to say:

> The assemble tool is very limited, I never had the need to extend it
>   further or add the features that you propose [...]

Answer (score 0):

[PVRTexTool](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtextool.asp) supports DDS export of texture arrays and cubemaps. Not sure if it supports cubemap arrays.